# Mongodb: how to sum at breaks in 2 fields?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document sample as follows:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5dfa4f7b9254a519a5c7f166"),
  Date: "12/11/19",
  Description: "Amazon",
  Amount: 32.01,
  DebitCredit: "debit",
  Category: "Shopping",
  Month: 12,
  Day: 11,
  Year: 2019,
  Account_Name: "Gold Delta SkyMiles"
}...
```

This is my query:

```
db.checks.aggregate([
  { $match: { Category: "Shopping" } },
  { $project: { Year: 1, Month: 1, Category: 1, Amount: { $sum: "$Amount" } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        Year: "$Year",
        Month: "$Month",
        Category: "$Category",
        Amount: { $sum: "$Amount" }
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { Year: 1, Month: 1 } }
]);
```

I'm looking for a total by each year / month combination. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to tweak your `$group` stage a little:
From the docs:

> Groups input documents by the specified _id expression and for each distinct grouping

So all we have to do is take out the `amount` field outside of the `_id` field.

```
{
    $group: {
      _id: {
        Year: "$Year",
        Month: "$Month",
      },
      Amount: { $sum: "$Amount" }
    }
}
```

- I removed `category` as it was redundant but feel free to add it back to your query.

EDIT:

For the `$sort` stage the fields `Year` & `Month` do not exists after the `$group` which is the reason its failing.

After the `$group` stage your documents are of the form:

```
{
    _id: {Year: number, Month: number},
    Amount: number
}
```

So just change your `$sort` into:

```
{ $sort: { '_id.Year': 1, '_id.Month': 1 } }
```

Comment: This worked! I couldn't find this in any documentation so thanks! (however my sort is still off).

Comment: i added it to my answer.